# Custom ComboBox Style Can't see Selected Item Text

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've been working on a custom combo box style based on the one here:

https://gist.github.com/HalidCisse/50df055a0c02714a9e3f

The problem I'm having is that the selected item text does not show up when I select an item or set some text to be shown by default. However if I set it so the combo box is editable I can see a blue outline the length of my text, where it should be. This makes me think the text is actually bound and being displayed, it's just invisible or hidden. Unfortunately I've been messing with this for a couple of hours and I've had no luck trying to unhide it.

[What it looks like when something is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtzPd.png)

This is how I have combo box setup:

```
<ComboBox     Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}"
              Height="40"
              FontSize="16"
              Margin="10 0 10 0"
              IsEnabled="True"
              IsEditable="True"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              Text="Testing Text">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 0"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 1"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

This is what I have:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxNormalBorderBrush"
                 Color="#333333" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush"
                 Color="#222222" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush"
                 Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush"
                 Color="#222222" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDisabledBorderBrush"
                 Color="#333333" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DropDownBackgroundBrush"
                 Color="#111111" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DropDownTextFillBrush"
                 Color="#FFFFB83D" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ArrowFillBrush"
                 Color="#FFFFB83D" />

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate"
                 TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Name="Border"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1, 1, 1, 1"
                CornerRadius="0" />
        <Border Name="ButtonBorder"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="1, 1, 1, 1"
                Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush}"
                BorderBrush="#444"
                BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 0"
                CornerRadius="0, 0, 0, 0" />

        <Path Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z"
              Fill="{StaticResource ArrowFillBrush}" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="Panel.Background" Value="#111111" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="{StaticResource ArrowFillBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="Panel.Background" Value="#111111" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="#999" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxFlatStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                     Color="#222222" />
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                      Margin="5, 3, 23, 3"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    <TextBox Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                             Margin="3, 3, 23, 3"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Background="Transparent"
                             Focusable="True"
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                             Visibility="Hidden">
                        <TextBox.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                                <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                        Focusable="False" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </TextBox.Template>
                    </TextBox>
                    <!--  Popup showing items  -->
                    <Popup Name="Popup"
                           AllowsTransparency="True"
                           Focusable="False"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Border Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Margin="0, 1, 0, 0"
                                    Background="{StaticResource DropDownBackgroundBrush}"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                                    CornerRadius="0" />
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                                  Grid.Column="2"
                                  ClickMode="Press"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                      Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="FrameworkElement.MinHeight" Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DropDownTextFillBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the order of the items in the combo box. I have been using the XAML styler extension for vs2013 and this can automatically format your xaml to make it look nicer. However I had a setting on that orders my elements automatically which meant the elements were being placed onto a empty grid in the wrong order, this obscuring the text.

For reference the correct order is:

ToggleButton

ContentPresenter

TextBox

Popup

Comment: XAML Styler does this because of the `Grid.Column="2"` on the `ToggleButton` (all others would default to `Grid.Column="0"`) - so when saving XAML Styler reorders the XAML based on `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Focusable="true"
```

Make this false, and you will see the selected text appearing. I dont understand why it is so, I too had similar issue, and it worked went setting the  `Focusable="False"`